# Android View.getTag returns null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view

I have an app where i have 2 buttons in a group which acts like a toggle button. Each button is assigned a static enum in its tag field using data binding as shown below:

xml

```
<data>
    <variable name="SortOrder" type="com.th3pl4gu3.lifestyle.core.operations.SortOperations.Order"/>
</data>

...

 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
            android:id="@id/BottomSheetDialog_fromFragmentBottomSheetSort_Sort_ToggleButtonGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Margin_ButtonGroup_Small"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/Margin_ButtonGroup_Default"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/Margin_ButtonGroup_Default"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/Margin_ButtonGroup_Default"
            app:singleSelection="true"
            app:checkedButton="@+id/BottomSheetDialog_fromFragmentBottomSheetSort_Sort_ToggleButtonGroup_Ascending">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@id/BottomSheetDialog_fromFragmentBottomSheetSort_Sort_ToggleButtonGroup_Ascending"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Fragment_BottomSheetDialog_Sort_ToggleButton_Ascending"
                android:tag="@{SortOrder.ASC}"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/custom_button_background_states"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"/>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@id/BottomSheetDialog_fromFragmentBottomSheetSort_Sort_ToggleButtonGroup_Descending"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Fragment_BottomSheetDialog_Sort_ToggleButton_Descending"
                android:tag="@{SortOrder.DESC}"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/custom_button_background_states"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"/>
    </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

And then in the code behind, i tried to get the tag as such:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    _binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_bottomdialog_sort, container, false)

    val button = _binding.root.findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.BottomSheetDialog_fromFragmentBottomSheetSort_Sort_ToggleButtonGroup_Ascending)

    val order = button.tag.toString()

    return _binding.root
}
```

However, this returns a **NullPointerException**

Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Can someone explain why and how i can get the tag in code behind ?

Answer (score 0):

You must set current Order when you bind view.
Must generated method like

```
_binding.serOrder(order :Order)
```

where you pass object.

You can bind data in on create without data bindibg

Comment: It's an enum, i don't need to bind it when generating the view. That's the purpose of an enum

Comment: Why are you not bind it onCreate?

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring a **variable** `SortOrder` of type `Order`. What you actually want is to **import** the type `Order` to use the enum in your layout:

```xml
<data>
    <import type="com.th3pl4gu3.lifestyle.core.operations.SortOperations.Order"/>
</data>
```

---

If you want to use it under the name `SortOrder` instead of `Order`, add the `alias` attribute:

```xml
<data>
    <import type="com.th3pl4gu3.lifestyle.core.operations.SortOperations.Order" alias="SortOrder"/>
</data>
```